# VHDL Error(10482) object std_logic_vector is used but not declared

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, quartus

I have written some code about an 8-bit adder using full adders as components.  When I start the compilation, it shows one error that I am not able to find.  I may have other mistakes that I can't notice.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity F_A is
  port(
        a,b,c_in : in std_logic;
        sum,c_out : out std_logic);
end F_A;

architecture behave of F_A is
begin 
  sum <= a xor b xor c_in;
  c_out <= (a and b)or(a and c_in)or(b and c_in);
end behave;

entity Adder_8bit is
  port( a,b: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Cin: in std_logic;
        sum: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Cout: out std_logic);
end Adder_8bit;

architecture RTL of Adder_8bit is
   signal c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   component F_A
      port( a,b,c_in : in std_logic;
            sum,c_out: out std_logic);
   end component;
   begin
     FA0 : F_A 
           port map(a(0),b(0),Cin,sum(0),c(0));
     FA1 : F_A 
           port map(a(1),b(1),c(0),sum(1),c(1));
     FA2 : F_A 
           port map(a(2),b(2),c(1),sum(2),c(2));
     FA3 : F_A 
           port map(a(3),b(3),c(2),sum(3),c(3));
     FA4 : F_A 
           port map(a(4),b(4),c(3),sum(4),c(4));
     FA5 : F_A 
           port map(a(5),b(5),c(4),sum(5),c(5));
     FA6 : F_A 
           port map(a(6),b(6),c(5),sum(6),c(6));
     FA7 : F_A
           port map(a(7),b(7),c(6),sum(7),c(7));
     Cout <= c(7);
end RTL;
```

Here is the error that appears :

```
Error (10482): VHDL error at Adder_8bit.vhd(17): object "std_logic_vector" is used but not declared
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *context clause* applies to the following *primary design unit* (ie `entity` or `package`). You need to repeat it before every `entity`, ie:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Adder_8bit is
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same issue，and according to response of Quartus,if u define more than one entity in a file,u even need to write library blabla more than once,such as:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FA2 is
    port(
        a,b:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cin:in std_logic;
        f:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cout:out std_logic
);
end FA2;

architecture plus of FA2 is
    component FullAdder1
        port(
                a,b,cin:in std_logic;
                f,cout:out std_logic;
                p,g:buffer std_logic
        );
    end component;
    
    component Advanced
        port (
            p,g:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            cin:in std_logic;
            c:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
    signal p,g:std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal c:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
    blabla
end plus;



library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Advanced is
    port(
        p,g:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cin:in std_logic;
        c:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end Advanced;

architecture ad of Advanced is
begin
    process(p,g,cin)
    begin
        blabla
    end process;
end ad;
```

u need to notice that two entities above are in the same VHDL file